# using VB.net and C#.net in a ASP.net Webapplication

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET, and I am working on a project which contains two C# and one VB.NET projects.

I want to put it all in a single project.  How would I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix different languages within a same project - but it's simple enough to have a class library written in C# that's called by VB or vice versa.

It's *possible* that you could write your ASP.NET *pages* in one language and have other code written in another language in the same project - but I would personally try to keep the presentation part of the code in one project and the logic in another, with each project only using a single language.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new solution and then add the two projects to it. Set one of them as the startup project and you are done.

To create an empty solution, select new project and then under **Other Project Types**, choose **Visual Studio Solutions**>>**Blank Solution**